# How can I filter products by meta data in Woocommerce REST API?

Tags: android, api, woocommerce

I want to filter the product through metadata in my application.
Is there any such way?
Or is it possible to filter metadata in any other way?

```
websitelink.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/?meta_key=key&meta_value=value&consumer_key=ck&consumer_secret=cs
```

[image]

Comment: Have you already checked here? http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#libraries-and-tools and more specifically here: https://github.com/gilokimu/WooDroid

Comment: Yes I saw it, but I couldn't find the meta data filter.

Comment: Did you get an answer for this?

Comment: No! Brother :'(